# определить позицию страницы если событие scroll занято

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как определить позицию страницы, если событие .scroll занято плагином fullpage.js? Смысл в том, что нужно при скролле вниз убирать навигацию, а при скролле вверх ставить на место, [вот сайт](http://freehostblizz.tk/Nu/index1.html)

Comment: У события может быть несколько обработчиков, создайте свой и делайте то, что вам необходимо

Comment: из кода плагина:
As we are changing the top property of the page on scrolling, we can not use the traditional way to detect it.
пробовал с помощью .bind добавить прокрутку страницы но эффект тот же, другие события работают

Comment: Тогда используйте колбэки плагина. Например, [onSlideLeave](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onslideleave-anchorlink-index-slideindex-direction-nextslideindex), проверяйте индекс текущего и следующего слайда, сравнивайте и делайте выводы о направлении прокрутки

Comment: а лучше - onLeave, один из параметров которого `direction`: it will take the values **up** or **down** depending on the scrolling direction

Comment: да но проблема в том что это событие срабатывает когда я покидаю секцию, а не когда я немного прокрутил страницу вниз

Comment: может быть есть альтернатива .scroll, допустим определять позицию документа, есть начальная,есть текущая и в зависимости от этого строить условие?

Comment: не знаю, почему у вас возникает проблема. Взяла пример прямо с сайта вашего плагина, добавила колбэк `onLeave`, прокрутка вниз - меню прячется, вверх - появляется https://jsfiddle.net/pxftyxg1/

Comment: потому что это событие срабатывает при переходе с слайда на слайд, посмотрите мой сайт, мне нужно чтоб срабатывала при прокрутке

Comment: Тогда вас спасёт `scrollBar:true;`. Вернёт событие onscroll и вешайте на него обработчик. Как-то так: `$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  scrollBar:true
  });
 $(document).on('scroll', function(){
  console.log('scroll');
 });`

Comment: не спасло, при таком раскладе появляется базовая прокрутка но срабатывает она тогда когда переходишь на другой слайд...